# How to have multiple if conditions for one for-loop and append values for time series data in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I want to analyse the dataframe `df` using a for-loop and collate observed results in a table.

`df` looks like this:

```
    Timestamp                X  Y   a   b       c       Id
0   2000-10-26 10:08:27.060 18  14  0.0 24.5    120     18  
1   2000-10-26 10:39:24.310 18  13  1.0 24.0    100     18
2   2000-10-26 11:50:48.190 18  14  1.0 23.5    90      18
3   2000-10-26 17:18:07.610 18  14  1.0 23.5    140     18
```

for-loop looks something like this:

```
result_table = []
flag = 1

for i in range(x, len(df)):
    # Finding value1, value2
    if (flag == 1) & (df.loc[i, 'b'] > 30):
        value1 = df.loc[i, 'a']
        flag = 2

    elif (flag == 2) & (df.loc[i, 'b'] < 5):
        value2 = df.loc[i, 'a']
        flag = 1

    # Finding peak 
    if (df.loc[i, 'c'] > df.loc[i-1, 'c']) & (df.loc[i, 'c'] > df.loc[i+1, 'c']):
        peak = df.loc[i, 'c']
     
        ... 
    else:
        continue

        result_table.append(['value1', 'value2', 'peak'])
        final_table = pd.DataFrame(dataframe, columns= ['value1', 'value2', 'peak']
```

I want to collate the results in a dataframe, where each row consists of one `value1`, one `value2` and one `peak` value.
But the `if/elif/else` conditions are sometimes related, such as `if/elif`, and sometimes not, such as the two `if`s, how can I append the values so they are in the same row? If this is not correct, what's the proper way to do this?

Comment: What is the flag?

Comment: @BillyBonaros The flag becomes `2` when `b` >30, and `1` when `b` <5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put IF Else condition for all three data points (Value1, Value2 and Peak)

So when condition for Value1 is not met it will say value1 = ''

And remove Flag == from condition, If condition itself is there to determine value of flag why put it in condition.

Try like this:

```
if (df.loc[i, 'b'] > 30):
    value1 = df.loc[i, 'a']
    flag = 2
else:
    value1 = ''
    flag = ''

if (df.loc[i, 'b'] < 5):
    value2 = df.loc[i, 'a']
    flag = 1
else:
    value2 = ''
    flag = ''
```

Why even need two values, value1 and value2, to make it more simple remove value2 and add in Flag data point,

```
value = df.loc[i, 'a']

if (df.loc[i, 'b'] > 30):
    flag = 2
elif:(df.loc[i, 'b'] < 5):
    flag = 1
else:
    flag = ''
```

To append:

```
item = {'value': value, 'flag': flag, 'peak': peak}
result_table.append(item)
```

why 'x' in for loop code? is it variable from where you want to start iteration? If not get rid of it.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
```